# LINQ Get single result or null

Tags: c#, linq

is there any LINQ function that returns only 1 element when the list has 1 element and if the list is empty or has more than 1 element it return's null?
The SingleOrDefault throws an exception when the list have more than 1 element...

Comment: There is no inbuilt linq function for the behavior you want..

Comment: Do you mean one element _in general_ or one element _that matches some condition_?

Comment: one element that matches some condition

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write this method by yourself

```cs
var list = new List<object>();
var result = list.Count() == 1 ? list.FirstOrDefault() : null;
```

More performant option with taking only first two elements in a collection (as @canton7 mentioned in comments)

```cs
var result = list.Take(2).Count() == 1 ? list.FirstOrDefault() : null;
```

Also, [`Single`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,35e2ff5965cb4b7e) can be used instead of [`FirstOrDefault`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,8087366974af11d2), but both methods do the same, cast source sequence to `IList` and get the first element.

Since, per question, the source collection is `List<T>`, it'll make sense to use `List<T>` indexer and `Count` property

```cs
var result = list.Count == 1 ? list[0] : null;
```

Comment: Actually with the check on count you can just use `Single` instead of `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: Note that this might be unnecessarily expensive: you can stop checking once you see 2 elements

Comment: @canton7 Thanks, it's a good point, `list.Take(2).Count() == 1` make more sense here

Comment: @juharr That's a good point, thanks. Under the hood [`Single`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,35e2ff5965cb4b7e) does almost the same with [`FirstOrDefault`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,8087366974af11d2), cast to `IList` and gets the first item

Comment: @canton7 First `Single` doesn't iterate the entire collection.  It will stop as soon as it sees a second item.  Further in this case `Single` is only called if you have exactly one item.  Finally it has the bonus of throwing an exception if you messed up the logic and called it when there is more than one item.

Comment: @juharr Bleh, I keep thinking about the versions which take a predicate

Answer (score 2):

Nothing built in but it wouldn't be hard to implement without iterating twice:

```
public static T SingleOrNothing(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> pred)
{
    bool found = false;
    T result = default(T);
    foreach(T item in source)
    { 
        if(pred(item))
        {
            if(found)
                // an item was already found - return nothing
                return default(T);

            // one was not found yet - keep this item as possible result
            result = item;
            found = true;
        }
    }
    //either one item was found or none (result will be default)
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
var myList = new List<object>();
//get data into list
var result = myList.Count() == 1 ? myList.Single() : null;
if (result != null)
{
   myList.Add(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you a little advice :)
Try using LINQPad (there's a free version), when you have this kind of inquiries, it will help you a lot to improve your skills.

Your requiremente can be evaluated using some extention methods (Skip, Take, Count), take a look at this dummy code:

```
public class ListDemo
{
    public static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        //Try erasing some elements of this list, leave one element alone
        List<string> AccountNumbers = new List<string>(){ "CC13563", "CC13578", "CC13525", "CC13585", "CC13500" };

        var account = AccountNumbers.Skip(1).Any() ? null : AccountNumbers.SingleOrDefault();

        //If Account is null it won't display anything...
        Console.Write("The element of your list: " + account + "\n");   
    }
}
```

PD: this is LINQPad [link](https://www.linqpad.net/Download.aspx) please try it, don't just take the fish learn how to fish.